# SQL Server (Restore Options Page)

Tags: sql-server, restore

[image]

Hello,
kindly can anybody tell me what is the difference between the 2 options (Recovery State and Leave Source Database in the restoring state (WITH NORECOVERY)), - see the snapshot below please - and When I have to check the option : Leave Source Database in the restoring state (WITH NORECOVERY)?
any help please,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you restore a database you have the option to keep restoring additional files.  Such as if you are going to restore a FULL backup and then additional LOG or DIFF files to bring the database up to date.

WITH NORECOVERY - Leave the database in a state that allows additional files to be restored.

WITH RECOVERY - Brings the database online and ready for transactions.

If you use the WITH NORECOVERY switch, you will need to issue the RECOVERY command yourself, either with the last restore or in a separate command "RESTORE DATABASE [dbname] WITH RECOVERY;"

Comment: ok, but if I select an option from recovery state combo box, why I want to check\uncheck the option Leave Source Database in the restoring state (WITH NORECOVERY) below?? or what is this option for?

Comment: That option takes a tail-log backup of the DB, then puts it into NORECOVERY.  This, effectively, stops all writes/read to the DB and make it inaccessible to any user/application.  This also will help with 'cannot restore database because it is in use' error messages and can be used as an alternative to setting it to SINGLE_USER (which the GUI will do if you select 'close existing connections to the db'.

Comment: okay .. thanks, but another question please... does the SQL restore this tail-log after the restoration operation, if I selected this option?

Comment: No, the tail backup belongs to the prior backup chain.  It would not be restored automatically.  But could be used to bring the database back to where it was before you started the restore process.  I usually take a backup of a database before restoring onto it.  Are you restoring the database to an earlier point in time of the same database or are you refreshing development with a production copy./